# Order by is not working correctly in mysql 5.6.28

Tags: mysql

I am using `5.6.28` version of MySQL. In my.ini configuration file, I have set the
`max_length_for_sort_data = 2147483647` and also change other config but still not working properly as I don't receive my required data. any help will be appreciated.

I have made a custom storage engine. Do I have to change or implement any function to make it working correctly?

[Sample Data and Order by ASC and DESC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKgCZ.png)

[Show Create table and Schema of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZRqy.png)

Comment: share your query, some sample data, table structure etc.

Comment: @ZafarMalik I edited my question and added a sample data image.

Comment: Please provide outputs of following queries

1. select subConditionName,ActiveTime  from wow order by ActiveTime desc;

2. select subConditionName,ActiveTime  from wow order by ActiveTime ;

Comment: @FathahRehmanP Please Check your Query Results It is the Same Result As in Above Queries

Comment: What is the datatype of ActiveTime column?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP ActiveTime : dateTime(3)

Comment: @FathahRehmanP SubConditionName : Text

Comment: are you sure ActiveTime column data type is dateTime?

Comment: Yes @FathahRehmanP it is DateTime(3) . I show you Sample Query and Data . it is not working in all data types.

Comment: share the results of "show create table wow"

Comment: @ZafarMalik i have edit and share the result of show create table . please have a look. and thanks for time.

Comment: Until you can rule out your "custom storage engine", I think this is the wrong forum.

Comment: You have mentioned it as innodb while it is different engine so you can get help in right forum.

Comment: change your engine to innodb and retry.